# How Can I Use AirPlay Globally for System Sound?

Tags: audio, airplay

Is it possible (and how) to have all the system sound played on AirPlay? Or at least for some specific (random) application (e.g. Songbird)?

Comment: This question now has an answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/117643/60998. The question is not quite the same, but the accepted answer applies :-)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [AirFoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) by Rogue Amoeba. Plays any audio from your system via AirPlay.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a newer Mac with Mountain Lion you can also use it's built in AirPlay functionality.

Go to System Preferences->Sound and select Apple TV from the Output tab. This will play all system sound from your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this in Mountain Lion is to hold down the option key and click on the speaker icon in the menu bar. You then get a list of possible outputs, and will be able to send all audio to your Apple TV or other AirPlay device by selecting it.