# Airplay without itunes

Tags: audio, airplay

I have some remote speakers hooked up to an Airport Express. While they work with iTunes as intended, I would like to stream sound that I play in other applications. Is there some facility for using the remote speakers from the rest of the system?

From googling (nothing found so far) and looking at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105171/stream-dvd-audio-through-airplay), I get the impression that no ready-to-use solution is provided by Apple. Assuming this is the case, I'd be curious about commandline-oriented or implementation-level information: What do the remote speakers look like to the iTunes API? How does OS X handle sound output, and is there any chance of arranging for remote speakers to be exposed as a sound device at the OS level? I'm currently running Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8).

**Update:** a) Thanks to @TonyWilliams, I now know about AirPlay, a third party solution. Still hoping for information on doing it directly, though. b) I've also come across [this question,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110119/60998) which would allow a bit of commandline access to the airplay speakers (if I can get it to work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply go to System Preferences → Sound → Output and choose your output device. Lag applies here too.

[image]

Comment: Wow, indeed I can! I had no idea... and now I have no idea why I never found this before. :-S Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial solution, Airfoil from Rogue Amoeba will send your audio out via Airplay. $25.

http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

They also offer a free utility to turn your Mac into AirPlay speakers.

(Note that there is a noticeable lag so it's not good for such things as watching video on the Mac or playing games, but it's fine for audio from apps like Spotify.)

Comment: Thanks. Since there's no Apple-provided solution I'd like to approach it at a lower level, but third-party software will get the job done if necessary.